# Стоит ли добавлять scss стили в проект на Github?

Tags: github, scss

Задаю такой вопрос, так как понимаю, что scss не имеет никакой значимости для проекта на Github и просто занимает лишний вес.

Comment: А для чего собственно Вы заливаете проект на гитхаб? Значимость имеет, так как работа над проектом, подразумевает под собой работу с исходниками.

Comment: github pages (точнее, jekyll) умеет работать с scss из коробки, см. https://jekyllrb.com/docs/assets/. Имеет смысл добавить scss, но не добавлять сгенеренный css. Это если вопрос про github pages. Если нет - то тем более, имеет смысл в проекте хранить именно исходники, а не сгенеренные файлы.